# Read multiple files in Hive table by date range

Tags: hive

Let's imagine I store one file per day in a format:

```
/path/to/files/2016/07/31.csv
/path/to/files/2016/08/01.csv
/path/to/files/2016/08/02.csv
```

How can I read the files in a single Hive table for a given date range (for example from 2016-06-04 to 2016-08-03)?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the file structure/names ?

Comment: @cheseaux Only if there are no other options :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming every files follow the same schema, I would then suggest that you store the files with the following naming convention :

```
/path/to/files/dt=2016-07-31/data.csv
/path/to/files/dt=2016-08-01/data.csv
/path/to/files/dt=2016-08-02/data.csv
```

You could then create an external table partitioned by `dt` and pointing to the location `/path/to/files/`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE yourtable(id int, value int)
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/path/to/files/'
```

If you have several partitions and don't want to write `alter table yourtable add partition ...` queries for each one, you can simply use the repair command that will automatically add partitions.

```
msck repair table yourtable
```

You can then simply select data within a date range by specifying the partition range

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE dt BETWEEN '2016-06-04' and '2016-08-03'
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting solution... Let's wait for a while I hope to see a solution with no file name modifications. Btw... could you please clarify, are you suggesting to read all files and optimize next SELECT by the partitioning?

Comment: An external table will not read all the files, it does read only when you query the table and will look only at the partitions (files) you specify in your query.

Comment: I've already asked @waltersu - what is an overhead of reading, let's imagine, 2000 years of logs partitioned by dates?

Comment: What do you mean by "reading" ? Like I've said, the external table doesn't read anything until you issue a query, and then it will only read the data it needs (the partitions you specified)

Comment: Just to confirm... Does it means that only 61 files will be opened for reading out of ~2000*12 files?

Comment: @DmitryPetrov I've edited my answer, there was a small mistake by the file naming convention. The filenames don't matter, it's the parent folder  `dt=...` that indicate the partition name.

Answer (score 0):

**Without moving your file:**

1. Design your table schema. In hive shell, create the table (partitioned by date)
2. [Loading files into tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual%20DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables)
3. Query with HiveQL ( select * from table where dt between '2016-06-04 ' and '2016-08-03')

**Moving your file:**

1. Design your table schema. In hive shell, create the table (partitioned by date)
2. move `/path/to/files/2016/07/31.csv` under `/dbname.db/tableName/dt=2016-07-31`, then you'll have

   `/dbname.db/tableName/dt=2016-07-31/file1.csv
   /dbname.db/tableName/dt=2016-08-01/file1.csv
   /dbname.db/tableName/dt=2016-08-02/file1.csv`
3. load partition with

   `alter table tableName add partition (dt=2016-07-31);`

See [Add partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions)

Comment: Is it possible to avoid loading all files? Let's imagine I have logs for 2000 years :) and query them just by a couple of weeks or months. What is an overhead of reading 2000 years of (partitioned by dates) logs?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark-shell, read hive table

```
/path/to/data/user_info/dt=2016-07-31/0000-0
```

1.create sql

```
val sql = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `user_info`( `userid` string, `name` string) PARTITIONED BY ( `dt` string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' LOCATION 'hdfs://.../data/user_info'"
```

2. run it

```
spark.sql(sql)
```

3.load data

```
val rlt= spark.sql("alter table user_info add partition (dt=2016-09-21)")
```

4.now you can select data from table

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from user_info")
```